# Prove that concatenation of two formation sequences is a formation sequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

A sequence $\phi_{0}, \ldots, \phi_{n}$ is called a formation sequence of $\phi$ if $\phi_{n} = \phi$ and

- for all $i < n, $  $\phi_{i}$ is atomic, or
- $\phi_{i} = (\phi_{j} \ @\phi_{k})$ for some $j,k < i$, or
- $\phi_{i} = (\neg \phi_{j})$ for some $j < i$.

Prove that concatenation of two formation sequences is a formation sequence.

Comment: Consider the sequence $\varphi_0, \ldots \varphi_n,\varphi_{n+1}, \ldots \varphi_{n+m}$ where the first formation sequence is $\varphi_0, \ldots \varphi_n$ and the second one is $\psi_1=\varphi_{n+1}, \ldots \psi_m=\varphi_{n+m}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how do I continue from here?

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your post. [Here is a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference.